# Add a driver to a material property using Python

Tags: python, drivers

Is it possible to add a driver to a property in a shader using Python?

I managed to get driver_add working for other properties, but not shader properties. I can also print the property just fine.

```
selected_node = bpy.context.active_node
selected_node.driver_add("inputs[1].default_value", 0)
```

Do I need to format it differently for it to work?

The error message says

`property "inputs[1].default_value" not found`

The property itself is an input field of a Node Group I made by the way.

Comment: `mat.node_tree.driver_add('nodes["My Node Name"].inputs[1].default_value', 0)`

Comment: @scurest have you tested it? Doesn't work for me: https://i.imgur.com/Zs8ROCi.png

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady Quoted strings in fcurve data paths are "double quoted".

Comment: @scurest I fall for this a 2nd time... Thanks :D But still, have you tried it? I don't get an error after fixing the quotes but the field still doesn't become purple.

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady Yes, I have tried it. The field isn't purple because it isn't the "canonical" path to that datum, because you used a socket name instead of a number. Starting from a blank file, you can manually add a driver to a socket in the UI, then do `D.materials[X].node_tree.animation_data.drivers[0].dath_path` to see what data path Blender actually creates.

Comment: @scurest interesting... I didn't know this is "legal". I just checked and the driver works, and the actual value in the field is "ignored" (overriden by the driver).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't add a driver to the node, add it to the input:

```py
D.materials['Material'].node_tree.nodes['Principled BSDF'].inputs['Roughness'].driver_add('default_value')
```

`D` is an alias in console for `bpy.data`